# How to load JSON file to google Bigquery using node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm using fetch function for getting the attached JSON object, and using my node.js backend to load this JSON data to Bigquery using the following code:

```
await bigquery
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId).insert(JSON_obj)
```

But unfortunately getting the following error :

```
Unhandled rejection PartialFailureError: A failure occurred during this request
```

JSON OBJ

```
{
  "totalResults": 418,
  "profileInfo": {
    "profileId": "104881487",
    "profileName": "All Mobile App Data",
    "accountId": "64812694",
    "tableId": "ga:105536427",
    "internalWebPropertyId": "100521715",
    "webPropertyId": "UA-648333494-1"
  },
  "totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:users": "427",
    "ga:totalEvents": "682",
    "ga:eventValue": "0"
  },
  "query": {
    "max-results": 1000,
    "start-index": 1,
    "start-date": "today",
    "end-date": "today",
    "dimensions": "ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel,ga:dateHourMinute",
    "metrics": [
      "ga:users",
      "ga:totalEvents",
      "ga:eventValue"
    ],
    "ids": "ga:104831427",
    "sort": [
      "-ga:totalEvents"
    ]
  },
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:10483467&dimensions=ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel,ga:dateHourMinute&metrics=ga:users,ga:totalEvents,ga:eventValue&sort=-ga:totalEvents&start-date=today&end-date=today",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "ga:eventCategory",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:eventAction",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:eventLabel",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:dateHourMinute",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:users",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:totalEvents",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "ga:eventValue",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "containsSampledData": false,
  "id": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:104831427&dimensions=ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel,ga:dateHourMinute&metrics=ga:users,ga:totalEvents,ga:eventValue&sort=-ga:totalEvents&start-date=today&end-date=today",
  "itemsPerPage": 1000,
  "kind": "analytics#gaData",
  "rows": [
    [
      "video_screen",
      "click_on_screen",
      "false",
      "202011190517",
      "1",
      "32",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "video_screen",
      "click_on_screen",
      "false",
      "202011190730",
      "1",
      "17",
      "0"
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: What's the schema of y our table? Do you really want to store the whole JSON?

Comment: You right, this is the schema: 
eventCategory STRING NULLABLE 
eventAction STRING NULLABLE 
eventLabel STRING NULLABLE 
dateHourMinute STRING NULLABLE 
users INTEGER NULLABLE 
totalEvents INTEGER NULLABLE 
eventValue FLOAT NULLABLE

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a JSON to BigQuery Insert to table function, you need to provide only the required data. Here you provide a big big JSON and the library need to guess the data to get in it.

Personally I guess in the `rows` array, but I'm not sure. And I'm also not sure about the field order!!

So, extract the useful data from your JSON, format them as you want (CSV, JSON,...) and submit them to BigQuery. It will work better!

Comment: I tried to change it and insert it like this: `JSON_obj.rows`
but it's still not working, 

 `await bigquery
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId).insert(JSON_obj.rows)`

Comment: For upload as a JSON file, I need to store the object, get the path, and use load instead of insert (stream), but I can't upload the JSON due to a server issue so I tried to make it different.